# DAS and iSCSI together

Tags: dell-powervault

We have an existing setup of 1G iSCSI composed of 2 switches, couple MD3220i and a few Dell servers. We need to add extra servers and storage and I am leaning towards DAS with MD3420 and 3 Dell servers. I understand the limitation that it can only be expanded to 4 servers (redundant) with the MD3420, but can those servers also connect to the iSCSI switches if we put enough ethernet ports (will add 10G for future proofing) and access the LUN's on the MD3220i?

Also, I read esxi 6 does not support 512e drives. If we load those drives on MD3420 and expose the LUN's. Does that still create problem for esxi?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS and iSCSI MD3 arrays can coexist with connections to the same hosts just fine. Obviously they'd be hosting completely separate datastores, but there should be no problem doing that.

ESXi's support for specific hard drive types applies only to solutions where the individual hard drives are "exposed" directly to the hosts/servers. Stick to what is supported on the storage arrays themselves for hard drives, as they're just presenting virtualized/logical disks sitting on top of the RAID sets.

Comment: Thank you JimNim for your reply.